'Invalid authentication data. Re-Login' from VCS > GitHub in IntelliJ IDEA
I made a repo on the GitHub website, and I'm trying to open it in IntelliJ IDEA.
When I open the app (on Windows), I click Get from VCS > GitHub, where it instantly says this:  even when I haven't opened it that day yet and the software was closed. If I click Re-Login, then Log in via GitHub, it opens this tab in my browser:
I click Authorize in GitHub, and then it says Invalid authentication data. Re-Login all over again.
This happens any time I try to open any Java repo from GitHub. What's going on? How do I fix this?

This is most likely related to: https://blog.jetbrains.com/security/2024/06/updates-for-security-issue-affecting-intellij-based-ides-2023-1-and-github-plugin/
Please make sure you are using the versions mentioned in the blog above or latest (2024.2)
